# Tag statistics overflow long tag names in the Stack Exchange iOS application

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app

Accessing user statistics in the iPhone (6) mobile app, long tag names appear to overflow the tag name.

Example of `template-meta-programming` tag:

[image]

Comment: Note that the phone apps are not currently in development and this will almost certainly go unfixed for the foreseeable future